# Searching for item in each list item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a piece of code to check if there is in the list item a div called star rating. If it doesnt excist, add to the price tag an extra margin top (so i can level out these items). My JQuery is as followed

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li.product").each(function(){
        if($(".star-rating").length === 0) {            
            $("span.price").css({"margin-top" : "1em"});
        }
    });
});
```

This code works fine to a certain point. What it technically does is it doesnt check the specific list item but the whole document. Is there a way I can just check the specific list item and add to the `span.price`in that item the css? cause now it finds 4 times the star-rating (4 list items), while it is only in one list item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search under each `"li.product"`:

```
$("li.product").each(function(){
    if($(this).find(".star-rating").length === 0) {            
        $(this).find("span.price").css({"margin-top" : "1em"});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if($(".star-rating",this).length === 0) {            
            $("span.price",this).css({"margin-top" : "1em"});
        }
```

Add context parameter to jQuery method

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li.product').not(':has(.star-rating)').find("span.price").css({"margin-top" : "1em"});
```

Without "if" and "each" that's what Jquery is for...